# PHP - multi-d array values changing between foreach loops

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

New PHP user left scratching my head. This function contains two `foreach` loops nested in `if/else` the page is `index.php`. On `index.php`, the code works fine, and the page shows the last four items in the array.

However, if the page is **NOT** `index.php`, the array seems to have been affected by code in between the first and second `foreach` loop, and only shows as a 1D array with the first-level keys as integers. How do I fix this? I've gone through virtually every PHP documentation I can find with no success.

```
function list_products_html($products) {
//If page is INDEX.PHP, show only last 4 products in reverse order with PayPal drop-down and Add To Cart
if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "index.php") {
    $products_reverse = array_reverse($products, true);
    $products_new = array_slice($products_reverse, 0, 4, true);

    foreach ($products_new as $product_new_id => $product_new) {
        echo list_product_html($products_new);
        echo generate_paypal_form($products_new);
        echo '</li>';
        }

//Else, show all products
} else {

    foreach ($products as $product_id => $product) {
        echo list_product_html($products);
        echo generate_paypal_form($products);
        echo '</li>';
     }
    }
   }
```

In the first `foreach` loop, the `var_dump` shows my array as the following (which is correct):

```
array(8) { [101]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(15) "Logo Shirt, Red" ["img"]=> string(24) "img/shirts/shirt-101.jpg" ["price"]=> int(18) ["paypal"]=> string(13) "BJDE2BMPHMQ7Q" ["sizes"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(5) "Small" [1]=> string(6) "Medium" [2]=> string(5) "Large" [3]=> string(7) "X-Large" } } [102]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(26) "Mike the Frog Shirt, Black" ["img"]=> string(24) "img/shirts/shirt-102.jpg" ["price"]=> int(20) ["paypal"]=> string(13) "2H6VLSYHY3QC8" ["sizes"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(5) "Small" [1]=> string(6) "Medium" [2]=> string(5) "Large" [3]=> string(7) "X-Large" } } [103]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(25) "Mike the Frog Shirt, Blue" ["img"]=> string(24) "img/shirts/shirt-103.jpg" ["price"]=> int(20) ["paypal"]=> string(13) "MDP23L74U3F4L" ["sizes"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(5) "Small" [1]=> string(6) "Medium" [2]=> string(5) "Large" [3]=> string(7) "X-Large" } } [104]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(17) "Logo Shirt, Green" ["img"]=> string(24) "img/shirts/shirt-104.jpg" ["price"]=> int(18) ["paypal"]=> string(13) "Q39L2XSPANB3Y" ["sizes"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(5) "Small" [1]=> string(6) "Medium" [2]=> string(5) "Large" [3]=> string(7) "X-Large" } } [105]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(27) "Mike the Frog Shirt, Yellow" ["img"]=> string(24) "img/shirts/shirt-105.jpg" ["price"]=> int(25) ["paypal"]=> string(13) "7LVQ78CEPSKVN" ["sizes"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(5) "Small" [1]=> string(6) "Medium" [2]=> string(5) "Large" [3]=> string(7) "X-Large" } } [106]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(16) "Logo Shirt, Gray" ["img"]=> string(24) "img/shirts/shirt-106.jpg" ["price"]=> int(20) ["paypal"]=> string(13) "G9A9UEVWCTDQN" ["sizes"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(5) "Small" [1]=> string(6) "Medium" [2]=> string(5) "Large" [3]=> string(7) "X-Large" } } [107]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(21) "Logo Shirt, Turquoise" ["img"]=> string(24) "img/shirts/shirt-107.jpg" ["price"]=> int(20) ["paypal"]=> string(13) "NNERMRTJSTG6Q" ["sizes"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(5) "Small" [1]=> string(6) "Medium" [2]=> string(5) "Large" [3]=> string(7) "X-Large" } } [108]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(18) "Logo Shirt, Orange" ["img"]=> string(24) "img/shirts/shirt-108.jpg" ["price"]=> int(25) ["paypal"]=> string(13)
```

In the SECOND `foreach` loop, I am getting the

> "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

error, because `var_dump` for the same `$products` array shows the following:

> int(101) int(102) int(103) int(104) int(105) int(106) int(107)
>   int(108)

Comment: The only way you would get `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` is if `$products` is not an array. So therefore it must be different than when you run it on your index.php page.

Comment: I definitely `var_dump`ed `$products`, not `$product_id`, so that's not it. :(

Comment: in both your `foreach()` loops you define a `$key => $value`, but then access the original array -> `$products_new`(`echo list_product_html($products_new);`)/`$products`(`echo list_product_html($products);`). Why?

Comment: See "new PHP user" :3

Comment: Looks like you're calling the above mentioned function from different scripts (pages). So if you're calling it from `index.php` the code in the `if` block will be executed. If you're calling it from somewhere else, then the code in the `else` block will be executed. So the assumption that `the array seems to have been affected by code in between the first and second foreach loop` is wrong. Check what your `$products` looks like _before_ calling the above function (in the file which isn't `index.php`).

Comment: I believe you're correct @Havelock - let me dig back in on the `shirts.php` page where it's also being called, and the `else` is supposed to kick in.

Comment: @Havelock you were absolutely correct. `shirts.php` actually had both incorrect arguments, as well as an unnecessary extra `foreach` loop. An easily-avoided mess in general. I'm learning. Thanks everyone!